# Tuple of Tuple as data in DataFrame results in AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Say I've got sample data:

```py
sdata = [(1,(10,20,30)),
         (2,(100,20)),
         (3,(100,200,300))]

columns = [('Sn','Products')]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(([x[0],*x[1]] for x in sdata), schema=columns)
```

Getting error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

How to load this variable length data ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent tuples as StructType; but it has fixed fields. I am not sure about "variable length" tuples; but if your requirement is to support variable number of elements in a collection type, then you can either define an explicit schema:

```py
sdata = [(1,(10,20,30)),
         (2,(100,20)),
         (3,(100,200,300))]

schema = StructType([
  StructField('Sn', LongType()),
  StructField('Products', ArrayType(LongType())),
])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(sdata, schema=schema)

[Out]:
+---+---------------+
| Sn|       Products|
+---+---------------+
|  1|   [10, 20, 30]|
|  2|      [100, 20]|
|  3|[100, 200, 300]|
+---+---------------+
```

or use field directly as an array:

```py
sdata = [(1,[10,20,30]),
         (2,[100,20]),
         (3,[100,200,300])]

columns = ['Sn','Products']

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(sdata, schema=columns)

[Out]:
+---+---------------+
| Sn|       Products|
+---+---------------+
|  1|   [10, 20, 30]|
|  2|      [100, 20]|
|  3|[100, 200, 300]|
+---+---------------+
```

Comment: Yeah, with StructType -> StructField its taking variable length data. Otherwise even by explicitly specifying ArrayType I was getting error. Thanks @Azhar